# How can I show UIAlertController on top of all the other views from UIPopoverController?

Tags: uiview, uipopovercontroller, uiwindow, uialertcontroller

I am trying to show UIAlertController view while UIPopoverController view is open, but the alert view goes back of popover view like this.

[image]

How can I make the alert view to the foremost of the window?

Here is my code. Thank you.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"test" message:@"test" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                        {

                                        }]];

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by myself.

I was calling `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];` from NSObject class.

I handed the parent view controller itself to the NSObject class (which means delegated) and call like this:`[parentVC presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];`.